# Swift 5 - Validation in textfields through UIAlertView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uialertview, uialertcontroller

So I'm using `Swift 5` and working with `core data`. I'm trying to add validation to the textfields through the `UIAlertView`.

To give clarification to what my code already does:

- User presses a button which the iOS Photo Library Interface Pops up.
- Once photo is selected a `UIAlertView`pops up and asks me two enter texts in two textfields.
- Once that is done, the data is submitted to the database and displays the image and the texts that I entered onto a `TableViewCell`

**The issue?**

When submitting a blank text field, there is no prompt to tell the user to enter texts. It will just display the image only in the `UITableViewCell` without any texts which is the obvious result when inputting no strings.

**What do I want to achieve?**

To add a validation message to the user when they enter no text and cancel the process of submitting to the database.

**What I've already tried?**

*Please see below for code. Note: Submitting an image and texts to the database already works, my issue is with textfield validation*

```
func createBrandItem (with image:UIImage){
        let brandItem = Brand(context: managedObjectContext)
        brandItem.image = NSData(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3)!) as Data

        let inputAlert = UIAlertController(title: "New Brand", message: "Enter an item and a brand.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        inputAlert.addTextField { (textfield:UITextField) in
            textfield.placeholder = "Item"
        }
        inputAlert.addTextField { (textfield:UITextField) in
            textfield.placeholder = "Brand"
        }

        inputAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

            let itemTextField = inputAlert.textFields?.first
            let productTextField = inputAlert.textFields?.last

            if (itemTextField?.text!.isEmpty)! || (productTextField?.text!.isEmpty)! {

                let alertBlankInput = UIAlertController(title: "Blank Input", message: "Please don't leave the textfields empty.", preferredStyle: .alert)

                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel)

                alertBlankInput.addAction(okAction)

                self.present(alertBlankInput, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            if itemTextField?.text != "" && productTextField?.text != "" {
                        brandItem.item = itemTextField?.text
                        brandItem.brand = productTextField?.text

                        do{
                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                            self.loadData()
                        }
                        catch{
                            print("Could not save data \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                }))

                inputAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

                if self.presentedViewController == nil {
                    self.present(inputAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else {
                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    self.present(inputAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

**Breaking the code down**

The snippet below is what I tried adding to the `createBrandItem` function. When I add this `if`statement when debugging the app, it uses this conditional statement but also completes the conditional statement where it adds to the database.

```
if (itemTextField?.text!.isEmpty)! || (productTextField?.text!.isEmpty)! {

            let alertBlankInput = UIAlertController(title: "Blank Input", message: "Please don't leave the textfields empty.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel)

            alertBlankInput.addAction(okAction)

            self.present(alertBlankInput, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

The code below is the snippet which adds the data to the database.

```
let brandItem = Brand(context: managedObjectContext)
        brandItem.image = NSData(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3)!) as Data
```

---

```
if itemTextField?.text != "" && productTextField?.text != "" {
                    brandItem.item = itemTextField?.text
                    brandItem.brand = productTextField?.text

                    do{
                        try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        self.loadData()
                    }
                    catch{
                        print("Could not save data \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
```

**Summary**

How would I go if the textfields are empty and stops the process of submitting to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating your own child view controller which you present as a model dialogue, which would be more elegant and give you far greater control over the process flow.  However if you want to continue with an alert controller, you could make it work by creating the OK action in a disabled state:

```
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel)
okActions.isEnabled = false
inputAlert.addAction(okAction)
```

and then use textFields' delegates to validate the content of the text fields (you'd need to have a means to coordinate between the two textfields - you could  use the alertController's `textfields?` array to cross-check, or use local variables as flags) and when you're happy with the content of both

```
inputAlert.actions.filter({$0.title == "OK"  }).first?.isEnabled = true
```